# Visual Studio razor code editor. How to create event handler for events

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2022, code-completion

I have next code in the razor file

```
<button type="button" @onclick="ButtonBtnClick">Button</button>
```

Now I want to write code for ButtonBtnClick method but I can't because I don't know what parameters should the method have.

When I used WPF code editor, the editor could create empty correct method.

But in the razor. Can the editor create empty correct method?

F12 on 'onclick' doesn't jump me to the definition of the onclick event.

Right mouse click over the 'ButtonBtnClick' doesn't  offer to create a method.

Comment: A razor page is not a WPF page. Looks like you need to come to terms with HTML first.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0) it looks like the method could support no args, built-in args, or custom args.  It's probably worth a suggestion on the [razor-tooling GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/razor-tooling/issues)